# Distribute MonoTouch app to testers using Organizer?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am trying to archive my MonoTouch app and to supply it to our testers using Apple's/Xcode's organizer.

Can somebody tell me how to do that? In ObjC projects I can archive an application. But how can I achieve the same in MT/MonoDevelop?

My starting point was this documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

René

Comment: will your testers be installing it via itunes?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping, yes. Currently they come to my desk and get the app deployed from within MonoDevelop.

Comment: @Krumelur - do yourself a favor and look into testflightapp.com.  It's a free service for managing iOS beta tests.  I use if and find it a great timesaver.

Comment: Nice, but I don't want to send my internal apps into the cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The archive that Xcode provides is in the form of an .ipa file. This is a glorified zip file with a certain expected file structure.

The .ipa is made up of the following components:

- A folder named "Payload", which contains the compiled
  (release/iPhone) .app
- a 57x57 .png icon file (which is displayed while the app is being
  downloaded)
- a 512x512 .png file of the icon once again - however this has to
  renamed itunesartwork with no extension
- iTunesMetadata.plist - this contains information about the app,
  such as copyright name, genre, itemname, softwareIconNeedsShine (you
  can google what information this needs).

The way I package up our .ipa, is I have a folder called "App Packaging" which has all of these components already in, and I simply update the .app file whenever we do an upload, "Compress..." then rename the file to x.ipa (OS X will ask if you want to use this extension, make sure you select ("use .ipa" !).

You can then send the file to the testers to install via itunes. If the testers are all testing on devices that are iOS 4.0+ then it is possible to distribute this over the air as well but I can go into that only if you would like me to?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT - Over the air distribution**

It is possible to do over the air distribution of apps as well. We use it for distribution of an enterprise app we develop but it is possible to use it for testing purposes as well. It should be noted here that in order for the app to installed, the device needs to be included in the provisioning profile you signed the app with (but you knew that already!).

In order to do over the air, you need 3 things:

- the .ipa file we created earlier.
- a 57x57 .png icon file (same as the one included in the .ipa preferably)
- a file called "Manifest.plist"

The Manifest plist contains the following structure/information:

[image]

You'll then want to upload all of these files to your website/intranet etc. In order to download the app, you'll need to create a page that points to the Manifest.plist file and then then iOS takes care of the rest and downloads the app from the location specified in the manifest.

Comment: Please provide details on the "over the air" topic! We are all 4.0+

Comment: If installed via iTunes: the provisioning profile seems to be added automatically. Does iTunes login to my dev account to add the device? Does that mean, everybody who gets the IPA will be able to install and will reduce my 100 available devices? Scary!

Comment: Just another comment: youe manifest.plist did not work for me. I made one using this template and it works: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

There is now a much much easier way. On the Project menu in MonoDevelop, choose Publish to TestFlight.

You'll need a free TestFlightApp.com account, but it works great!

Comment: Yep, doing that meanwhile. But when I asked that question, there was no such easy way.